# How do I include short vertical lines in between links in navbar?

Tags: html, css

**What I'm looking for:**

[image: What I'm looking for] /

**What I've got:**

[image: What I've got]

I want to include small vertical lines, evenly spaced with matching color, in between the links in my navbar. Below is the CSS code I've written. I'm new to coding and I've searched Google but I keep seeing the same answer which got me these huge lines that I don't want. ???

```
    /* GLOBAL */
    body {
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: grey;
        font-family: 'Arial', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 300;
    }


    /* NAVBAR */
    header {
        background: #ffffff;
        max-width: 100%;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #777777;
    }

    header::after {
        content: '';
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }

    .container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 960px;
    }

    .logo {
        float: left;
        background-color: #4aaaa5;
        color: #ffffff;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 20px 30px;
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: 'Georgia', Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    }

    nav {
        float: right;
    }

    nav ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }

    nav li {
        display: inline-block;
        padding-top: 30px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        **border-right: 1px solid #777777;**  
    }

    nav a {
        color: #777777;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    nav li:last-of-type {
        **border-right: none;**
    } 

    nav a:hover {
        color: #4aaaa5;
    }

===========================================================================
 <body>
  <header>
   <div class="container">
    <h1 class="logo">Name</h1>
    <nav>
     <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="content.html">Content</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
   </div>
  </header>
 </body>
```

Comment: Can you please add your `HTML`

Comment: border left and right on the second element is sufficient if you only have 3 items

Comment: Updated with html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can consider using pseudo elements. That'll do the trick.

Have a look at this

```css
ul {
  list-style:none;
}
ul li{
  display:inline-block; 
  padding:0 7px; 
  position:relative;
}
ul li:not(:last-child)::after{
  content:""; 
  border:1px solid #e2e2e2;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
  position:absolute; 
  right:-3px; 
  top:0; 
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Portfolio</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the `border-right` to each `li` tag except the last `li` tag. And add padding to the each `li` tag.

like the below code

```
.nav li{
    border-right: 2px solid #c4c4c4;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
.nav li:last-child {
    border-right:0;
}
```

Below is the full working demo here. Hope it helps you.

```css
.nav{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 25px;
    float: left;
}
.nav li{
    border-right: 2px solid #c4c4c4;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
.nav li:last-child {
    border-right:0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a  href="#about">Home</a></li>
    <li><a  href="#about">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using border-right or the way below.

```css
.nav{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 25px;
    float: left;
}
.nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
.nav li::after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 2px;
    right: 0;
    content: ' ';
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.nav li:last-child::after {
   width: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a  href="#about">Home</a></li>
    <li><a  href="#about">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

### working demo

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a  href="#about">Home</a></li>
    <li><a  href="#about">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
.nav{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 25px;
    float: left;
}
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left:10px
    padding-right:10px;
}
.nav li:after{
    content:'|';
    display:inline-block;
    color:#dddddd;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.nav li:last-child:after {
     display:none;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Add the separator image as a background image on the li.

```
#nav li + li {
    background:url('seperator.gif') no-repeat top left;
    padding-left: 10px
}
```